# String turned into object after passing it to another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, magnific-popup

I have this function that gets the coordinates of a marker after it is dropped into a map:

```
$(function() {
$( "#add-marker" ).draggable({
    containment: "map",
    helper: "clone",
    start: function(evt, ui) {
        $('#navbar').fadeTo('fast', 0.6, function() {});
    },
    stop: function(evt, ui) {

        // Turning coordinates into a string and then removing unwanted characters
        var string = String(map.containerPointToLatLng([ui.offset.left, ui.offset.top]));

        string = string.replace('LatLng(', '');
        string = string.replace(' ', '');
        string = string.replace(')', '');
        console.log(typeof string); // ---> Shows my coordinates
        addProperty(string);
    }
});
});
```

The problem is that when I pass "string", it is converted into an object:

```
function addProperty(coords){
$.magnificPopup.open({
    tLoading:"Loading...",
    modal:false,
    showCloseBtn: true,
    closeBtnInside: true,
    type:'inline',
    alignTop:false,
    items:{src: $('#test-popup')},
    callbacks: {
        open: function(coords) {
            console.log(typeof $(this).data(coords)); // ---> Shows object
            $('#coords').val($(this).data(coords));
        }
    }
});
}
```

How can I pass "string" to the addProperty function and still have it as a string?

Comment: `$(this).data(coords)` What it is returning?

Comment: Note that while `string` isn't a reserved word, it's not a great variable name as it will cause a lot of confusion.

Comment: Rajaprabhu: it returns object. Rory: you're right, I changed it to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example, you're dealing with `coords` value from `open` callback, not the one from the higher function `addProperty`.

To fix this, simply rename `coords` variable name from `open` callback :

```
function addProperty(coords) {

  $.magnificPopup.open({

    callbacks: {

      open: function(newCoords) {
        /* 
           Here, you can access coords wich is still the string version,
           or newCoords wich is the new object returned by the callback.
        */
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: So how would I fix it?

Comment: I simplified my post. Do you see the difference ? You have two variables now: `coords` and `newCoords`.

Comment: It works. But logging `typeof $(this).data(coords)` will always return an object because that's the way `data` method of jQuery works. See documentation : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but it really is not working. The function is supposed to fill the #coords field with the coordinates and I get [object Object]

Comment: Simply fill the field like this then : `$('#coords').val(coords)` :) Why using jQuery.data ?

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! For some reason, I was seeing some cached version and changes weren't reflecting immediately!

Answer (score 1):

You will have a much easier time if you access the `lat` and `lng` properties of the `L.LatLng` object returned by `containerPointToLatLng`:

```
stop: function(evt, ui) {

    var ll = map.containerPointToLatLng([ui.offset.left, ui.offset.top]);

    var str = '' + ll.lat.toFixed(4) + ',' + ll.lng.toFixed(4);

    addProperty(str);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this simplified things a lot!